# Vow combos java

Tags: java, logic

so I'm having problems with my code. My objective is to count and properly use the boolean "insideVowelGroup". I want to know how to count the vowls if say two vowls are next to eachother it counts as one. Almost finished please help

```
public int countSyllables() {
      count = 0;
  int upperLimit = word.length() - 1;
  if (upperLimit < 0) {
     return 0;   // empty String
  }
  char c = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(upperLimit));
  if (c == 'e') {
     upperLimit--;  // if e at the end of the word, omit it;
  }                                      // don't want to count as vowel

  boolean insideVowelGroup = false;  // indicates vowel/combo found
  for (int i = 0; i <= upperLimit; i++) // look at each character
  {  // check for inside vowel and/or vowel combination
     c = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i));
     if ("aeiouy".indexOf(c) >= 0) // check for c == vowel
     {
        if (insideVowelGroup) // no vowel/or combo vowel yet
        {                      // Start new vowel group
           count++;
           insideVowelGroup = true;
        }
     }

  } // end for loop
  if (count == 0) {
     count++;  // every word has at least one syllable
  }
  return count;
```

}

Comment: You just didn't say what problem is it that you are having.

Comment: I also don't see a clear problem statement here.  You just dumped a bunch of code with a few comments.  Please tell us clearly what this code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what these codes are doing until I make some "intelligent" guesses here and there.

I think the problem is here:

```
if (insideVowelGroup) // no vowel/or combo vowel yet
{                      // Start new vowel group
   count++;
   insideVowelGroup = true;
}
```

You probably need this:

```
if ("aeiouy".indexOf(c) >= 0)
{
    if (!insideVowelGroup) // Your mistake is here
    {
       count++;
       insideVowelGroup = true;
    }
}
else
{
    insideVowelGroup = false; // You need to reset it if
                              // the character is not a vowel character
}
```